# Guardar dato tipo byte en campo varbinary(max)

Tags: c#, sql-server

estoy haciendo una aplicación para guardar los datos de una huella dactilar, pero no queda, la huella la paso por un metodo para poder convertirla en byte[], como en el codigo:

```
private void ControlHuellas_OnEnroll(object Control, int FingerMask, DPFP.Template Template, ref DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus EventHandlerStatus)
    {
        if(lidEmpleado.Text == "" || lidEmpleado.Text == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selecciona el empleado para registrar sus huellas", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            Byte[] bytes = null;

            if (Template is null)
            {
                Template.Serialize(ref bytes);
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo realizar la operación", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                pbFotoEmpleado.Image = null;
                lidEmpleado.Text = "";
                lNombreEmpleado.Text = "";
                lDepartamento.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                DataTable IdE = biss.VerificarEmpleado(Convert.ToInt32(lidEmpleado.Text));
                if (IdE.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    Template.Serialize(ref bytes);
                    biss.ActualizarHuellas(Convert.ToInt32(lidEmpleado.Text), bytes);//aqui mando los datos para actualizar la tabla y que me inserte la huella

                    lidEmpleado.Text = "";
                    lNombreEmpleado.Text = "";
                    lDepartamento.Text = "";
                    pbFotoEmpleado.Image = null;
                    MessageBox.Show("La Huella Dactilar Ha Sido Registrada", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

depues de esto la mando a otra clase donde tengo el metodo para que me inserte la huella en la base de datos:
este es el codigo que uso para guardar la huella:

```
public Boolean ActualizarHuellas(int idEmpleado, Byte[] finger)
    {
        try
        {
            String query = "stp_UpdateHuella_GetbyId @idEmp = " + idEmpleado + ", @Huella = " + finger + "";
            //String query = "UPDATE ImgE SET Huella =" + finger + " WHERE idEmp = " + idEmpleado +"";
            data.update(query);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

pero me manda el siguiente error:

> {"Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '.'.\r\nFalta o está vacío un nombre de objeto o columna. Compruebe si todas las columnas de las instrucciones SELECT INTO tienen un nombre. Para otras instrucciones, busque si hay nombres de alias vacíos. No se permiten los alias definidos como \"\" o []. Cambie el alias por un nombre válido."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se que hace `data.update()` pero sino permite asignar parametros entonces deberias cambiarlo, concatenar valor en un string no es una buena practica.

Tu codigo deberia lucir como esto

```
public Boolean ActualizarHuellas(int idEmpleado, Byte[] finger)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionstring = "connectionstring";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring)) 
        { 
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("stp_UpdateHuella_GetbyId", conn); 
            cmd.CommandType = SqlCommandType.StoredProcedure; 

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idEmp", idEmpleado); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Huella", finger);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Como veras se asignan los valores a la coleccion `Parameters` y solo se define el nombre del procedure indicando el `CommandType`